# Why do asymmetric specular highlights appear in a scene with only ambient lighting in Unity?

Tags: unity, graphics, lighting

I have a scene in Unity (2019.3.0f3 Personal) using the High-Definition Render Pipeline. There are no lights in the scene, and Baked Global Illumination is disabled. The skybox is a `GradientSky`. By all means, the lighting in the scene should be absolutely uniform, but instead there is a gradient from one side to the other.

This is what the scene looks like:
[image: normal scene]

Though the effect is faint, you can see that the right side of the plane is slightly lighter than the left. The ground shader is `HDRP/TesselationLit`, and by bringing the `Smoothness Remapping` to max I can exaggerate this effect, as shown below. This is why I am under the impression the effect is specular in nature.

[image: increased smoothness]

Interestingly, if I switch the camera to the Isometric mode, the effect disappears:

[image: isometric mode]

Finally, the effect appears to occur in world rather than camera space, as shown by the changes in lighting when I rotate my camera in increments of 90 degrees:

[image: rotations of camera]

What is causing this effect, and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving the problem on my own. The texture type of normal map for the material assigned to the ground was set to `Default`, and setting it to `Normal map` resolved the problem. Duh...